# How to calculate 'age last birthday' on a given date for a given birthday in SAS PROC SQL step

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I want to calculate '[age last birthday](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=6621)' on a specific evaluation date, given a specific date of birth, using a SAS `PROC SQL` command.

How can I do this and are there any limitations?

**Sample Input**

```
DATA INPUTS;
infile cards dlm=',' dsd;
INPUT  DOBDt :DATE9. EvalDt :DATE9. expected;
FORMAT DOBDt date9. EvalDt date9.;
CARDS;
11MAY2009,10MAY2015,5
11MAY2009,11MAY2015,6
11MAY2009,12MAY2015,6
28FEB1984,01DEC2015,31
29FEB1984,28FEB2012,27
29FEB1984,29FEB2012,28
29FEB1984,01MAR2012,28
;
RUN;
```

The goal would be to take the `dobDt` as an input, evaluate on the `EvalDt` and produce the answer of `expected`

Comment: There's a good post here on how to calculate age in SAS http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2011/07/12/computing-age-in-sas-9-3/

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, what does 'age last birthday on a specific evaluation date' mean.  Ideally, you should also post what you've tried.  Glad you found your own answer though.

Comment: Reeza - over the past couple of years I've asked this question a couple of times and I never find the answer on stackoverflow. I thought it might help others to have my solution posted here as there are a lot of 'bad'/approximate answers on other sites.

Comment: that's fine, but the phrasing of your question is awkward and unclear. Is it the calculation of age at a specified date? Or is there some other complication that I'm not getting?

Comment: I added a link to the definition of 'age last birthday' to clarify. (I believe the problem with this calculation in SAS and lack of a canonical example is that prior to version 9.2 there was no inbuilt functionality to calculate this result; as a result the internet is littered with broken/approximate code examples that don't actually calculate this value correctly).

Comment: So 'age last birthday' is ... age?  I think you should simplify the title to just 'Calculate age in SAS' and then update the post to reflect that.  You may also want to replace the 'sql' tag with 'proc-sql' so that people reading the vanilla 'sql' tag don't get confused.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as such :

**PROC SQL**

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE outputs2 AS
    select
        *
        ,intck('year',DOBDt,EvalDt,'c')      AS actual
        ,((calculated actual) eq expected)   AS check
    FROM
        inputs
;
QUIT;
```

`actual`, the calculated value, matches `expected`, the desired outcome, for all the examples provided. I am not aware of any limitations to this approach although there are probably some extreme ages that it cannot calculate due to SAS dates having a limited range of values.

As a bonus:

**DATA STEP**

```
DATA outputs;
set inputs;
    actual = intck('year',DOBDt,EvalDt,'c');
    check  = (actual eq expected);
RUN;
```

Comment: Limitation - requires SAS 9.2 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we used to do it back in the day.  Also "age at last birthday" seems pretty clear to me.

```
DATA INPUTS;
   infile cards dlm=',' dsd;
   INPUT  DOBDt :DATE9. EvalDt :DATE9. expected;
   FORMAT DOBDt date9. EvalDt date9.;
   age = year(evaldt)-year(dobdt) - (month(evaldt) eq month(dobdt) and day(evaldt) lt day(dobdt)) - (month(evaldt) lt month(dobdt));
   CARDS;
11MAY2009,10MAY2015,5
11MAY2009,11MAY2015,6
11MAY2009,12MAY2015,6
28FEB1984,01DEC2015,31
29FEB1984,28FEB2012,27
29FEB1984,29FEB2012,28
29FEB1984,01MAR2012,28
;;;;
   RUN;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't look right.  Fails when month(EvalDt) < month (DOBDt).  Maybe one more `- (month(evaldt)< month(dobdt))` at the end?